# access google custom search from my android application

Tags: google-custom-search

I m trying to develop an android application which takes recipe name from user and internally search recipe of entered name from Google custom search and give it user. 
But i do not understand how to access Google custom search from my android application. Please help me to get out of this.
Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Google provides a [JSON/ATOM Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/introduction). That would be the way to go about integrating the Search into your Android application.

To make the integration processes easier into any client application and avoid doing all the REST stuff in your code, there are a number of client libraries made available. Take a [look](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/libraries).

Be aware of the pricing i.e. free quota v/s billing.